# Counting singularities

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

It is well known that a smooth vector field on a 2-sphere must vanish twice.

What is the general technique for counting singularities of a smooth map between manifolds? For example, how many singularities must a smooth, surjective map $\phi: V \rightarrow SU(n)$ possess? Here $V$ is a finite dim vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Can this be established via any analogous method to the vector field on the sphere.

Comment: The first sentence isn't a special case of the second sentence. Anyway, for maps to $\mathbb{R}$ what you want is called Morse theory, and for vector fields what you want is called the Poincare-Hopf theorem. I don't know what the general situation is.

Comment: I realize that it's not exactly a special case. I just wondered if there was something in the same spirit using the Euler characteristic.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "singularities." In the case of maps to $\mathbb{R}$ I mean points at which the derivative vanishes, but in the case of vector fields I mean points at which the vector field vanishes. I don't know what you mean for a map to $SU(n)$.

Comment: Points where the Jacobian has rank less than the largest possible rank.

Comment: The first sentence is false. Wikipedia kindly provides a counterexample: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Hairy_ball_one_pole.jpg

Comment: It is true if you include the multiplicity of the zero

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your first case. Section 9 of Heinz Hopf's [lecture notes on differential geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=qvpsCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=section%209%20the%20role%20of%20the%20euler%20characteristic%20in%20the%20theory%20vector%20fields&source=bl&ots=358W9cZxJ-&sig=RVv39RkA4iyUNOQyCrthmII48qw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dcpnVf3oBMHaoASC94DICg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=section%209%20the%20role%20of%20the%20euler%20characteristic%20in%20the%20theory%20vector%20fields&f=false) is called: "the role of the euler characteristic in the theory vector fields" which generalizes your first statements to surfaces:

**Theorem:** Summing up the singularity of *any* vector field on a surface, gives the Euler characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

Well here's maybe a somewhat enlightening example. Any smooth map $f:M\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ where $M$ is an $m$-dimensional closed compact manifold has infinitely many singularities (for $n\geq 2$ and $m\geq n$). If $f$ only had finitely many singularities, then $f(M)\subset \Bbb R^n$ would be compact with non-empty interior and hence have infinite topological boundary (for $n\geq 2$). By the inverse function theorem, a topological boundary point must be a critical value.

In fact using a little covering space theory, we can conclude from this that any map from $S^2$ to a closed orientable surface of genus $\geq 1$ also has infinitely many singularities.

Generically, I do not think one should expect there to even exist maps where singularities are isolated, so the case where the target is $\Bbb R$ (as in Morse theory) is quite special.

**Edit:** Here's a further generalization of the above that should be easy for anyone interested to fill in the details. Let $M$, $N$ be smooth compact manifolds (without boundary) with $\operatorname{dim}M \geq \operatorname{dim}N$. If we have $p(\pi_1(M))$ has infinite index in $\pi_1(N)$ for any homomorphism $p: \pi_1(M) \rightarrow \pi_1(N)$, then any map $f:M \rightarrow N$ has infinitely many singularities.

Comment: I tried to up vote this, but it won't let me! Sorry +1